# TypeOrm query builder

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I can't figure out how to write the following MySql statement using TypeOrm Query Builder

> SELECT reg.id FROM farm.reg WHERE grpId = 'ABC';

this select is returning just the id's but my query builder is returning the entire objects.

In this moment I have this function in my NestJs service but I need to use 'map' and I don't want to..

```
 async getGrupIds(entity: string, grpId: string) {

        console.log(entity, grpId);
        const ids = await getRepository(reg)
        .createQueryBuilder(entity)
        .where('reg.grpId = :grpId', {grpId: grpId})
        .getMany();
        console.log(ids);
        return ids.map(o => o.id);

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use getRawMany() instead of getMany() if you want to select some specified fields of your entity:

```
//I suppose you have a *grpId* variable in your function 

const ids = await getRepository(Reg)
    .createQueryBuilder('reg')
    .select('reg.grpId', 'id')
    .where('reg.grpId = :grpId', { grpId } )
    .getRawMany();
    console.log(ids);
    return ids    
}
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-values-using-querybuilder

Comment: async getGroupIds(entity: string, grpId: string) {
      
        const ids = await getRepository(reg)
        .createQueryBuilder(entity)
        .select('reg.id')
        .where('reg.grpId = :grpId', {grpId: grpId})
        .getRawMany();
        console.log(ids);
        // return ids.map(o => o.id);
        return ids
    }
works like a charm, many thanks!